# CSS code not working on one single page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margin, menuitem

For my workplace, I had to make a new website through wordpress/avada, and so far everything is going great, except the following:

A button in the menu is currently sitting like this: https://gyazo.com/00850a7c32e4eb3d22c4d7dd7158ad38

But it needs to be shifted down like on [this page](http://outdoortycoon.com/brands/life-line/)

I identified the menu item/button:

```
<li role="menuitem" id="menu-item-2660" class="b2b-login-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2660" data-classes="b2b-login-menu">
    <a href="http://shop.bemontex.com/webstore" class="fusion-flex-link"><span class="fusion-megamenu-icon"><i class="fa glyphicon fa-user-circle"></i></span><span class="menu-text">B2B Login</span></a>
</li>
```

And gave it the following attributes:

```
#menu-item-2660 {
    margin-top: 18px !important;
}
```

The css code above works on every single page, except the home page.

Anyone know why this happened? I emptied my browser cache multiple times and tested it on different browsers and devices, but still no luck...

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Ok just checked your website and it is not picking up the style sheet for where you have declared the 18px top margin - if you add the 18px top margin on your homepage too it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a cache issue:

http://outdoortycoon.com/?bust=dacache

Find your cache settings and clear it (or just wait) and the problem will go away.

To clarify: It's **not** your *browser* cache - it's your *server* cache. That might be a wordpress plugin like WP-supercache, w3 or something similar, or it could even be a caching service such as cloudflare or similar. It's not possible for me to know what you are using, but you need to identify a server-side cache and clear that...

Comment: Mikk3lRo's answer worked! Really weird, since I flushed the cache multiple times, but doing it through a wordpress plugin actually worked. 

Solved! Thanks for all the answers people :)

Comment: I was just clarifying what I meant by "cache" when you found it yourself ;)

Comment: Haha yeah, it was WP-Supercache that was acting up. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid using margins in this situation, and opt to throw `position: relative` with a `top: 2rem` or something on there. But with that said, I think this theme may be weird, and not all the CSS loads on every page. Make sure that that CSS file is being loaded.